# Numpy .all() ignores IndexError

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say  we have the following array:

```
a = np.zeros((3,3,3))
```

single checks are working:

`a[1,1,1] == 0` --> True

`a[5,1,1] == 0` --> IndexError

checking an area  of the array  don't show the indexError

`(a[0:2,0:2,0:2] == 0).all()`  --> True

`(a[0:20,0:2,0:2] == 0).all()`  --> True  is the result, but it should be  an IndexError

In such cases  I would like to get a False  or at least the error, any hints?

Comment: A slice like `a[0:20,0:2,0:2]` does not produce an index error for example: `np.array([1, 2, 3])[0:20]` -> `np.array([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: P.S.: At the moment  I handle  this case with some if statements before, but  there is probably a way  how  to throw  the False in such a case

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking the bounds of the array beforehand. However, if you really want to, one way to accomplish this would be to pad the array with a value that will compare not equal to all numbers, such as `None`:

```
a = np.zeros((3, 3))
padded = np.pad(a.astype(object), [(0, 1), (0, 1)], 'constant', constant_values=None)

print((a[:3, :3] == 0).all())
print((a[:4, :4] == 0).all())

print((padded[:3, :3] == 0).all())
print((padded[:4, :4] == 0).all())
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
False
```

Note that this requires converting your array to `object` type.

Answer (score 0):

By default with numpy arrays, if the index is bigger than the dimension, then it returns until the last elements it finds.

I'm not sure if you can change this behaviour though. The only solution I can think of is to check first if the indices are lower than the size of each dimension and do the comparison after.

Comment: Huh? Numpy gives an `IndexError` when you index past the end of an array. This is an error: `np.array([1, 2, 3])[3]`

Comment: My bad, I meant if you sliced it

Comment: This is consistent with the way ordinary list slicing works. `[1, 2, 3][1:10]` doesn't report an error.